# Image file path error while using pandoc for markdown to pdf conversion

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown file with images in the same directory as the `.md` file, e.g. with `![Image test ](test.png)` in the `.md` file.

I convert them into `pdf` through`pandoc`:

```
pandoc --standalone --pdf-engine=xelatex file.md -o output.pdf
```

and I get the following error

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'test.png': replacing image with description
```

However, with the same directory I have no issues while converting `.md` into `.html` output. Can someone suggest what is the issue with pandoc?

Comment: Weird, that should work. Are you calling pandoc from the same directory, i.e. the one where `file.md` is placed? You could also try to set the `--resource-path` option to make sure the image will be found.

Comment: yes, I get the `.pdf` output but without the images.

Comment: As a quick test, maybe you could try using an absolute path (one that begins with slash, like `/home/users/joe/image.jpg`) to see if the problem is finding the image or understanding its format.

Comment: I have tried that before, it does not find the image, infact I get no images in my `html` too with absolute file path

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I just tried it with the MRE being just a line specifying the image.  When the image was in the current working directory, it was fine.  When it was elsewhere, I got the error message, even if it was in the same directory as `file.md`, which is reasonable, I think.